# Time delay in js function load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There seems to be a time delay before the below mention functions starts to work. I'm not able to identify why it is so. Could anybody guide me on this??

The images do show initially but without the fade in or fade out effect but once all the images are done going the first loop, the animation works.

JS:

```
$(function fadeAnimation() {
  $(".imageClass img:gt(0)").hide();
  setInterval(function fadeAnimation() {
    $(".imageClass :first-child")
      .fadeOut(3000)
      .next("img")
      .fadeIn(3000)
      .end()
      .appendTo(".imageClass");
  }, 5500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slidesDiv" id="cust">
<img class="imageClass" src="images/Folder1/1.jpg?" alt="" />
<img class="imageClass" src="images/Folder1/2.jpg?" alt="" />
<img class="imageClass" src="images/Folder1/3.jpg?" alt="" />
<img class="imageClass" src="images/Folder1/4.jpg?" alt="" />
<img class="imageClass" src="images/Folder1/5.jpg?" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: You must hide the html by default. Then show it and animate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues in your code.

1. `.imageClass` are the `<img>`... You have to use the container's class, which is `.slidesDiv`.
2. You have to use the callback of the animations... Now, both `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut` are executing at the same moment.
3. Your timing is wrong... The animations are taking 6 seconds, but you have set the interval to 5,5 seconds.

See comments in code for the details.

```js
$(function fadeAnimation() {

  // Hide all image
  $(".slidesDiv img").hide();

  // Fade the first in right away.
  $(".slidesDiv :first-child")
    .fadeIn(3000);

  // Start the interval to loo through all image
  // The interval will execute for the first time in 6 seconds from now.
  setInterval(function fadeAnimation() {
  
    // Fade the first out.
    $(".slidesDiv :first-child")
      .fadeOut(3000, function(){ // This is a "callback" when the fade out is complete
        
        // Fade In the next image
        $(this).next("img")
          .fadeIn(3000);
          
        // append the faded out image to the end of the container.
        $(this).appendTo(".slidesDiv");
      });
  }, 6000);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slidesDiv" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".imageClass img:gt(0)").hide();` this was a mistake on my part... Thank you so much..

Comment: I sort of solved it by having css value for display as none for the images. Now the jQuery function works as expected.

Comment: Now, I'm using the changes you made. I've created 7 such functions with varying setInterval. The functions take time of the maximum setInterval to start running. Any idea on how I can make them independent? and start right away?

Comment: The only way to have an interval that looks like "starting right away" is to define a named function, example: `function myFunction(){ console.log("Hello!"); }` and then run it once... And also use that function as the interval callback `setInterval(myFunction,1000);`